# Need some insight on a Simple Text Game I'm working on for school

Tags: python-3.x

So heres my code.

```
rooms = {
        'Great Hall': {'South': 'Bedroom'},
        'Bedroom': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar'},
        'Cellar': {'West': 'Bedroom'}
    }

print('Welcome To The Room Game')
print('Move Commands: South, North, East, West, exit')
print('---------------------------------------------------------------')

print('Enter your move:')


for room in rooms:
    print('You are in {}'.format(room))

    for direction in rooms[room]:
        print('You are in {}'.format(direction, rooms[room][direction]))
```

heres the output

```
Welcome To The Room Game
Move Commands: South, North, East, West, exit
---------------------------------------------------------------
Enter your move:
You are in Great Hall
You are in South
You are in Bedroom
You are in North
You are in East
You are in Cellar
You are in West
```

Its not prompting me to put in a direction. any help is appreciated.

I havent tried anything beyond this.

it should display this.

```
You are in the Great Hall
Enter Your move:
```

Then I type a direction either North, South, East, West, or exit

Answer (score -1):

To get an input in python, you have to use a special function called `input()` this is similar to a print statement, except it lets you input a value which is returned as a string.
Instead of doing:

```
print("Enter your move: ")
```

put this in:

```
move = input("Enter your move: ")
```

Then you are also looping through all of your rooms?
I would do it like this, where you store the current room, and set it as a new one after getting the input.

```
rooms = {
        'Great Hall': {'South': 'Bedroom'},
        'Bedroom': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar'},
        'Cellar': {'West': 'Bedroom'}
    }

print('Welcome To The Room Game')
print('Move Commands: South, North, East, West, exit')
print('---------------------------------------------------------------')

room = "Great Hall"

while True:
    print('You are in {}'.format(room))
    move = input("Enter your move: ")

    try:
        room = rooms[room][move]
    except KeyError:
        print("You can't go that way!")
```